# How could I modify the following table?

Tags: tables

Thanks to the generous help of this forum, I have generate the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{6}{l} }
  \caption{Gene Expression of Final Results }\label{tab:geneExpression}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & $Log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$ & T-statistic & P-value & Adj. p-value & B-statistic\\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \ref{tab:geneExpression}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & $Log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$ & T-statistic & T-value & Adj. p-value & B-statistic
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
  \rowcolor{red!40}
  1 & PIK3CA & 0.510433149 & 4.08637044 & 0.000396781 & 0.001323525 & -0.770996675 \\
  \rowcolor{red!40}
  2 & PTK2 & 1.213119481 & 6.20213251 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 & 4.647379763 \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
  1 & FGFR2 & -3.123519832 & -8.933085516 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 & 11.08760121 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
  2 & FAM101B & -0.930032202 & -6.112796226 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 & 4.422184915 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
  3 & P2RY5 & -0.889380357 & -5.576441313 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 & 3.057020258 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
  4 & PDE2A & -0.553052729 & -3.986387839 & 0.000513085 & 0.001662448 & -1.023529359 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
  5 & VPS53 & -0.628374531 & -5.709313148 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 & 3.397059848 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I think that there is too much color. I would like to add a left column like the following:

[image]

"variable1" would be in red, span 2 individual rows and be called "Amplification". "variable2" would be in blue, span 5 individual rows and be called "Deletion." Essentially, there would be two coloured cells. I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

EDIT:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{6}{l} }
  \caption{Gene Expression of Final Results }\label{tab:geneExpression}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & $Log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$ & T-statistic & P-value & Adj. p-value & B-statistic\\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \ref{tab:geneExpression}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & $log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$ & t-statistic & p-value & adj. p-value & B-statistic
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
  \cellcolor{red!40}Amplification & PIK3CA & 0.510433149 & 4.08637044 & 0.000396781 & 0.001323525 & -0.770996675 \\
  \cline{2-7}
   & PTK2 & 1.213119481 & 6.20213251 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 & 4.647379763 \\
   & PTK2 & 0.463127075 & 4.493947177 & 0.00013835 & 0.000513205 & 0.269169211 \\
  \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!40}\multicolumn{1}{l}{Deletion} & FGFR2 & -3.123520 & -8.933086 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 11.087601 \\ 
   & FGFR2 & -2.517900 & -7.915850 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 8.799095 \\ 
  & FGFR2 &  -2.506299 & -8.029605 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 9.061846 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.466978 & -7.828476 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 8.596126 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.456237 & -7.142357 & 0.000000 & 0.000001 & 6.968246 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.447313 & -7.512376 & 0.000000 & 0.000001 & 7.853556 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.445145 & -7.720149 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 8.343102 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.432399 & -7.708434 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 8.315647 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.422551 & -7.645426 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 8.167680 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.391726 & -7.488984 & 0.000000 & 0.000001 & 7.798096 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.198940 & -6.702346 & 0.000001 & 0.000003 & 5.894072 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -0.940757 & -4.386494 & 0.000183 & 0.000660 & -0.006389 \\ 
  \cline{2-7}
  & FAM101B & -0.930032202 & -6.112796226 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 & 4.422184915 \\
  \cline{2-7}
  & P2RY5 & -0.889380357 & -5.576441313 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 & 3.057020258 \\
  & P2RY5 & -0.8874392 & -7.708377 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 & 8.315513 \\
  \cline{2-7}
  & PDE2A & -0.553052729 & -3.986387839 & 0.000513085 & 0.001662448 & -1.023529359 \\
  \cline{2-7}
  & VPS53 & -0.628374531 & -5.709313148 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 & 3.397059848 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{8}{l}}
  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue & qValueRes\\ 
   \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue & qValueRes\\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \hline
  \endlastfoot

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.368e-03 & 2.180e-02 \\
2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.058e-06 & 1.411e-03 \\
3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.536e-01 & 1.536e-01 \\
5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.536e-01 & 1.536e-01 \\
6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.536e-01 & 1.536e-01 \\
7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.733e-13 & 1.100e-07 \\
9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.394e-02 & 1.434e-01 \\
11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.394e-02 & 1.434e-01 \\
12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.141e-03 & 9.789e-03 \\
13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.911e-02 & 6.605e-01 \\
16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.911e-02 & 6.605e-01 \\
17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.141e-03 & 9.789e-03 \\
18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.252e-04 & 2.252e-04 \\
19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.665e-06 & 4.799e-03 \\
20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.665e-06 & 4.799e-03 \\
21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.669e-18 & 1.469e-12 \\
22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.669e-18 & 1.469e-12 \\
23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.059e-02 & 8.621e-02 \\
24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.232e-21 & 4.232e-21 \\
25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.232e-21 & 4.232e-21 \\
26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.261e-02 & 2.261e-02 \\
27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.172e-02 & 8.621e-02 \\
28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.457e-03 & 8.051e-03 \\
29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.261e-02 & 2.241e-01 \\
30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.261e-02 & 2.241e-01 \\
31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.261e-02 & 2.241e-01 \\
32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.173e-03 & 3.202e-02 \\
34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.173e-03 & 3.202e-02 \\
35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.911e-02 & 6.605e-01 \\
36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.911e-02 & 6.605e-01 \\
37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.058e-06 & 1.411e-03 \\
38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.172e-02 & 8.621e-02 \\
39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.090e-02 & 2.019e-01 \\
41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.329e-02 & 1.484e-01 \\
42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.172e-02 & 8.621e-02 \\
43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.368e-03 & 2.180e-02 \\
44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.368e-03 & 2.180e-02 \\
45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.536e-01 & 1.536e-01 \\
46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.368e-03 & 2.180e-02 \\
47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.141e-03 & 9.789e-03 \\
50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.261e-02 & 2.241e-01 \\
51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.058e-06 & 1.411e-03 \\
52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.058e-06 & 1.411e-03 \\
53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.490e-11 & 8.370e-08 \\
54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.500e-02 & 1.500e-02 \\
55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.368e-03 & 2.180e-02 \\
56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.368e-03 & 2.180e-02 \\
57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.261e-02 & 2.241e-01 \\
58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.521e-03 & 1.631e-02 \\
59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.435e-02 & 1.116e-01 \\
60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.141e-21 & 5.814e-11 \\
61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.141e-21 & 5.814e-11 \\
62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.362e-02 & 6.394e-02 \\
64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.198e-01 & 1.484e-01 \\
71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.826e-03 & 5.702e-02 \\
72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.826e-03 & 5.702e-02 \\
73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.261e-02 & 2.241e-01 \\
74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.513e-06 & 1.555e-04 \\
75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.513e-06 & 1.555e-04 \\
76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.513e-06 & 1.555e-04 \\
77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.513e-06 & 1.555e-04 \\
78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.141e-03 & 9.789e-03 \\
79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.563e-02 & 5.281e-02 \\
80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.051e-03 & 2.761e-02 \\
81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.980e-08 & 1.980e-08 \\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've already figured out the main point, which (I think) was to change the values of blueness and redness in rows 1/2 and 3-7, respectively.

Some further suggestions that may help make the table more visually appealing (and easier to parse):

- Since most of the numbers in the tables contain decimal points, it's useful to align them on the decimal markers. One way to do this is to use the `S` column type, which is provided by the `siunitx` package. (Aside: is it necessary to show 8 or 9 digits after the decimal? Might 3 or 4 digits be every bit as informative?)
- Some of the numbers in the p-value and adjusted p-value columns are given in decimal form, others in "scientific" form. I'd standardize on the scientific notation form.
- For better-spaced horizontal lines, consider using the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "S" column type macro
\sisetup{tight-spacing, group-digits=false}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ r l 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=-1.9]} 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=1.2e-2]}
                        S[table-format=-1.9] }
  \caption{Gene Expression of Final Results }\label{tab:geneExpression}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & {$\log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$} & {T-statistic} & {P-value} & {Adj.\ p-value} & {B-statistic}\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \ref{tab:geneExpression}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
  & Gene & {$\log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$} & {T-statistic} & {P-value} & {Adj. p-value} & {B-statistic}\\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  \rowcolor{red!10}
  1 & PIK3CA & 0.510433149 & 4.08637044 & 3.97e-4 & 1.32e-3 & -0.770996675 \\
  \rowcolor{red!10}
  2 & PTK2 & 1.213119481 & 6.20213251 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 & 4.647379763 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!10}
  1 & FGFR2 & -3.123519832 & -8.933085516 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 & 11.08760121 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!10}
  2 & FAM101B & -0.930032202 & -6.112796226 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 & 4.422184915 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!10}
  3 & P2RY5 & -0.889380357 & -5.576441313 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 & 3.057020258 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!10}
  4 & PDE2A & -0.553052729 & -3.986387839 & 5.13e-4 & 1.66e-3 & -1.023529359 \\
  \rowcolor{blue!10}
  5 & VPS53 & -0.628374531 & -5.709313148 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 & 3.397059848 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's the same table, but with an extra column (for the words "Amplification" and "Deletion") and without colors. (IMNSHO, coloring the rows doesn't do anything for the table except provide a touch of gaudiness.) You may still want to think about cutting down on the number of digits shown in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
%%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
%%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "S" column type macro
\sisetup{tight-spacing, group-digits=false}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}  %default value: 6pt
\begin{longtable}{ @{} lll 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=-1.9]} 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=1.2e-1]}
                        S[table-format=-1.9] @{}}
  \caption{Gene Expression of Final Results }\label{tab:geneExpression}\\
  \toprule
  & & Gene & {$\log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$} & {T-statistic} & {P-value} & {Adj.\ P-value} & {B-statistic}\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \ref{tab:geneExpression}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
  & & Gene & {$\log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$} & {T-statistic} & {P-value} & {Adj.\ P-value} & {B-statistic}\\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  %\rowcolor{red!10}
  Amplification & 1 & PIK3CA & 0.510433149 & 4.08637044 & 3.97e-4 & 1.32e-3 & -0.770996675 \\
  %\rowcolor{red!10}
  & 2 & PTK2 & 1.213119481 & 6.20213251 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 & 4.647379763 \\
  %\rowcolor{blue!10}
  \addlinespace
  Deletion & 1 & FGFR2 & -3.123519832 & -8.933085516 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 & 11.08760121 \\
  %\rowcolor{blue!10}
  & 2 & FAM101B & -0.930032202 & -6.112796226 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 & 4.422184915 \\
  %\rowcolor{blue!10}
  & 3 & P2RY5 & -0.889380357 & -5.576441313 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 & 3.057020258 \\
  %\rowcolor{blue!10}
  & 4 & PDE2A & -0.553052729 & -3.986387839 & 5.13e-4 & 1.66e-3 & -1.023529359 \\
  %\rowcolor{blue!10}
  & 5 & VPS53 & -0.628374531 & -5.709313148 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 & 3.397059848 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you you very much! I have uploaded the code that I made yesterday.  Your solution is a more accurate and elegant!

Comment: Hi! I don't understand

\begin{longtable}  {r l  
                   *{2}{S[table-format=-1.9]} 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=1.2e-2]}
                        S[table-format=-1.9] }

Thank you!

Comment: @Johnathan - Please see the user guide of the `siunitx` package for a detailed explanation of the `S` column type and its many options. Basically, `-1.9` sets aside 9 digits after the decimal marker and 1 digit plus enough space for a minus symbol before the decimal marker.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have added a second table (EDIT 2) with proper decimals in scientific notation as you recommended. I am trying to get latex to convert e02 to x10^2 like in your example. In my thesis, I have several tables with scientific notation (I am currently retouching them). I am having a hard time learning how to instruct latex to parse columns and automatically convert into scientific notation.

Comment: @Johnathan - Would you mind posting the material in "Edit2" as a *new* question, making the new question specifically about formatting numeric data, some of which may be in decimal format whereas other parts are in scientific format? That way, more people will see it and have a chance to come up with answers.

Comment: Hi! I worked a lot on my tables today and have improved them. However, I have another question with scientific notation. :)
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246514/cell-padding-and-scientific-notation-doesnt-work-in-both-tables