# Cell padding and scientific notation doesn't work in both tables

Tags: tables

I have made the following two:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, caption, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{table-format =1.2e-2}
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\ 
   \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.73e-13 & 1.10e-07 \\
9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\
11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\
12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.25e-04 & 2.25e-04 \\
19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\
20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\
21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\
22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\
23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.06e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\
25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\
26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.26e-02 & 2.26e-02 \\
27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.46e-03 & 8.05e-03 \\
29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\
34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\
35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.09e-02 & 2.02e-01 \\
41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.33e-02 & 1.48e-01 \\
42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.49e-11 & 8.37e-08 \\
54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.50e-02 & 1.50e-02 \\
55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.52e-03 & 1.63e-02 \\
59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.44e-02 & 1.12e-01 \\
60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\
61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\
62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.36e-02 & 6.39e-02 \\
64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.20e-01 & 1.48e-01 \\
71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\
72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\
73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.05e-03 & 2.76e-02 \\
81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 & 1.98e-08 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{table-format =1.2e-2}
\begin{longtable}{Cr *{5}{c}SS}

  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes4}\\
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Gene} & \textit{log}(FC) & \textit{t} & p-value & Adj. \textit{p}-value \\ 
   \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes4}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  Amplification & \multicolumn{1}{l}{PIK3CA} & 0.51 & 4.09 & 3.97e-04 & 1.32e-03 \\ 
   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{PTK2} & 1.21 & 6.20 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 \\  
   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{PTK2} & 0.46 & 4.49 & 1.38e-04 & 5.13e-04 \\ 
   \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Deletion} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -3.12 & -8.93 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.52 & -7.92 & 2.85e-08 & 2.77e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.51 & -8.03 & 2.20e-08 & 2.22e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.47 & -7.83 & 3.48e-08 & 3.31e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.46 & -7.14 & 1.74e-07 & 1.37e-06 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.45 & -7.72 & 4.47e-08 & 4.13e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.45 & -7.51 & 7.25e-08 & 6.31e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.43 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.42 & -7.65 & 5.32e-08 & 4.81e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.39 & -7.49 & 7.66e-08 & 6.63e-07 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -2.20 & -6.70 & 5.04e-07 & 3.50e-06 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FGFR2} & -0.94 & -4.39 & 1.83e-04 & 6.60e-04 \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FAM101B} & -0.93 & -6.11 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 \\ 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{P2RY5} & -0.89 & -5.58 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{P2RY5} & -0.89 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{PDE2A} & -0.55 & -3.99 & 5.13e-4 & 1.66e-3 \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{VPS53} & -0.63 & -5.71 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The first table is exactly what I want. However, the second table should work but doesn't ... It must be something silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say the first table works to your liking, my answer addresses only the second table. I suggest making the following changes:

- delete the instruction `\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}`, as 2 of the 4 data columns are in ordinary (i.e., decimal notation) format
- use `S[table-format =-1.2]` as the column type for the first two numeric columns
- use `S[table-format =1.2e-1]` as the column type for the final two numeric columns
- I would use `l` as the column type for the first two columns
- fix the column count used in the `\endhead` and `\endfoot` areas: the table contains 6 rather than just 5 columns
- touch up the information given in the header cells here and there; encase the headers of the four `S` columns in curly braces in order to center them (since they are *not* numeric)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, caption, %cellspace, 
            booktabs}
%\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
%\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}
\begin{longtable}{@{} ll *{2}{S[table-format = -1.2]} 
                         *{2}{S[table-format =  1.2e-1]} @{}}

  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin--Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes4}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & {$\log(FC)$} & {\textit{t}-stat} & {\textit{p}-value} & {Adj.\ \textit{p}-value} \\ 
   \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes4}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
  & Gene & {$\log(FC)$} & {\textit{t}-stat} & {\textit{p}-value} & {Adj.\ \textit{p}-value} \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  Amplification & PIK3CA & 0.51 & 4.09 & 3.97e-04 & 1.32e-03 \\ 
  & PTK2 & 1.21 & 6.20 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 \\  
  & PTK2 & 0.46 & 4.49 & 1.38e-04 & 5.13e-04 \\ 
   \addlinespace
  Deletion & FGFR2 & -3.12 & -8.93 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 \\
  & FGFR2 & -2.52 & -7.92 & 2.85e-08 & 2.77e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.51 & -8.03 & 2.20e-08 & 2.22e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.47 & -7.83 & 3.48e-08 & 3.31e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.46 & -7.14 & 1.74e-07 & 1.37e-06 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.45 & -7.72 & 4.47e-08 & 4.13e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.45 & -7.51 & 7.25e-08 & 6.31e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.43 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.42 & -7.65 & 5.32e-08 & 4.81e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.39 & -7.49 & 7.66e-08 & 6.63e-07 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -2.20 & -6.70 & 5.04e-07 & 3.50e-06 \\ 
  & FGFR2 & -0.94 & -4.39 & 1.83e-04 & 6.60e-04 \\
  & FAM101B & -0.93 & -6.11 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 \\ 
  & P2RY5 & -0.89 & -5.58 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 \\
  & P2RY5 & -0.89 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\
  & PDE2A & -0.55 & -3.99 & 5.13e-4 & 1.66e-3 \\
  & VPS53 & -0.63 & -5.71 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

  -

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have a question for \begin 
When you wrote ll *{2}{S[table-format = -1.2]} 
                         *{2}{S[table-format =  1.2e-1]} @{}}

Does latex see this as 6 columns? I am simply confused about how to "specific which column to do what" Thanks!

Comment: @Johnathan -- The table has six columns: The first two are of type `l`, the next two are of type `S` (with option `table-format = -1.2`), and the final two are of type `S` as well (but with formatting option `table-format = 1.2e-1`). The `@{}` particles tell LaTeX to suppress the whitespace that's otherwise inserted to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column.

Comment: @Johnathan - Don't forget to upvote answers you find useful. :-;  By now, you have enough reputation points to upvote both questions and answers.